# Mysql query configuration

Tags: mysql

I have this query and runs perfectly, i just want to short the results to help me for quick reading   :

```
SELECT numbers 
FROM vista 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT b.id + 3 FROM(
      SELECT t1.id, t1.numbers t1val, t2.numbers t2val
      FROM vista t1 
      JOIN vista t2 ON t1.id = t2.id-1 
      JOIN vista t3 ON t1.id = t3.id-2 
      WHERE t1.id = (SELECT MAX(id) - 2 FROM vista)
    ) a
    JOIN (
      SELECT t1.id, t1.numbers t1val, t2.numbers t2val, t3.numbers t3val 
      FROM vista t1 
      JOIN vista t2 ON t1.id = t2.id-1 
      JOIN vista t3 ON t1.id = t3.id-2 
      WHERE t1.id < (SELECT MAX(id) - 2 FROM vista)
    ) b 
  ON a.t1val = b.t1val 
  AND a.t2val = b.t2val 
  AND a.t3val = b.t3val 
  AND a.id <> b.id
) 
ORDER BY id;
```

**And the results it is like :**

```
3
5
2
7
5
5
7
3
```

How can i get results counted in group and percentage :

Like :

```
5 = 3 (37.50%)
7 = 2 (25.00%)
3 = 2 (25.00%)
2 = 1 (12.50%)
```

Comment: You need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your query works than you should do something like this to achieve result you want:

**Solution one** - this will give you numbers, countend numbers in group and percentage in seperate column...

```
SELECT numbers, COUNT(numbers), (COUNT(numbers) / (SELECT COUNT(numbers) 
                                 FROM vista
                                 /*your WHERE clause*/)) * 100 AS percent 
FROM vista 
-- your WHERE Statement
GROUP BY numbers
-- your ORDER BY
```

Here is a sql fiddle to see how that's look like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08b4e/3

**Solution two** - this will give you numbers in one column and counted numbers in group and percentage in other:

```
 SELECT numbers, CONCAT(CountNum, ' (', percent, '%)') AS counted
 FROM (SELECT numbers, COUNT(numbers) AS CountNum, (COUNT(numbers) / (SELECT COUNT(numbers) 
                                                  FROM vista
                                                  WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 8
                                                  /*your WHERE clause*/)) * 100 AS percent
       FROM vista 
       WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 8
       -- your WHERE clause this is just for a testing purpose
       GROUP BY numbers
       ORDER BY ID) AS srcTable
       -- your ORDER BY clause this is just for a testing purpose
```

Here is Fiddle for that http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51275/1

Of course you need to insert your **WHERE** clause instead of mine i just put this one to test it. GL i hope i help a little.